# Compare multiple values of an array in the same time in Javascript

Tags: javascript, angular-2+

As of now the below code working As expected. But in future if the **newFilterArr** have new record again I want to reedit this functionality. So how to overcome this?

```
function Optimiz() {
    let courseFilter = this.newFilterArr.find(k => k.key === 'courseId'),
        rateTypeFilter = this.newFilterArr.find(k => k.key === 'rateTypeId');

    this.rateSetupDataUI = this.originalRateSetupDataUI.filter(x => {
        if (courseFilter && rateTypeFilter) {
            return x['courseId'] === courseFilter.filtered.id && x['rateTypeId'] === rateTypeFilter.filtered.id;
        } else if (courseFilter && !rateTypeFilter) {
            return x['courseId'] === courseFilter.filtered.id
        } else if (!courseFilter && rateTypeFilter) {
            return x['rateTypeId'] === rateTypeFilter.filtered.id;
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
let courseFilter = this.newFilterArr.find(k => k.key === 'courseId'),
    rateTypeFilter = this.newFilterArr.find(k => k.key === 'rateTypeId');
```

I would consider making your filter an object instead of an array. The keys are probably unique and known ahead of time, thus could be a type.

```
    if (courseFilter && rateTypeFilter) {
        return x['courseId'] === courseFilter.filtered.id && x['rateTypeId'] === rateTypeFilter.filtered.id;
    } else if (courseFilter && !rateTypeFilter) {
        return x['courseId'] === courseFilter.filtered.id
    } else if (!courseFilter && rateTypeFilter) {
        return x['rateTypeId'] === rateTypeFilter.filtered.id;
    }
```

This code is a good example of a function doing too many things. You can just progressively filter, filtering by `courseId` first, and whatever results from that, you filter with `rateTypeId`.  The condition with the `&&` is not necessary.

This could be rewritten as:

```
class Filter {
  courseId:string
  rateTypeId:string
}

function Optimiz() {
  const filter:Filter = this.newFilterObj

  // Match only if filter is a truthy value. Otherwise, just add it.
  this.rateSetupDataUi = this.originalRateSetupDataUI
    .filter(x => filter.courseId ? x.courseId === filter.courseId : true)
    .filter(x => filter.rateTypeId ? x.rateTypeId === filter.rateTypeId : true)
}
```

### Nitpicks

- I advise against a single `let`/`var`/`const` and recommend a `let`/`var`/`const` *per* variable. Prepending/appending requires needlessly modifying the first and last lines, respectively. And if you move variables around, you will still have to add `let`/`var`/`const`.
- `x['courseId']` and `x['rateTypeId']` don't need to be in bracket notation, as the property names don't have invalid characters.